# Second .xib file won't link to .swift file for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an XCode project that has multiple UITableViews within it. One of the tables is for items in an inventory to be displayed. The other table is in a separate UIViewController and displays active accounts and allows the user to change account numbers and change other account properties. I created the .xib file for the inventory UITableViewCell no problem, and it links to the corresponding .swift file in the assistant view. But when I created the second .xib file for the accounts table, it wouldn't link to the .swift file I created for that cell. It keeps showing me a file titled NSObject. I've got the classes for the two UITableViewCells named appropriately. I've closed out of XCode and reopened. I have no idea why the assistant view would work fine for one .xib file but not the other... is there anything I can do to force the .xib file to link to the correct .swift file?

Comment: Make sure to set the name of "File's Owner" for the UITableViewCell

Comment: I tried that at well, but then the assistant view shows nothing.

Comment: Maybe just manually add an editor - `File` -> `New` -> `Editor`, and then navigate to the path of your file at the top of the screen

Comment: Try delete the xib and swift files and recreate them